# How to rewrite the beginning and end of the permalink structure in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've created a custom post type called "dvposts" and cannot get the permalink structure to display exactly as I want.

My regular post/page structure is `/%postname%/%post_id%/`.

I would like my custom post type structure to be `/d/%postname%/%post_id%/`, with the `/d` at the beginning. I would also like `/d/` to open `archive.php`.

By sending certain arguments to register_post_type() I've been able to get

1. `/d/%postname%/` and archive at `/d/` with

   ```
   'has_archive' => true,
   'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'd'),
   ```
2. `/%postname%/%post_id%/` and archive at `/dvposts/` with

   ```
   'has_archive' => true,
   // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'd'),
   ```
3. `/dvposts/%postname%/` and archive at `/d/` with

   ```
   'has_archive' => 'd',
   // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'd'),
   ```
4. `/d/%postname%/` and archive at `/d/` with

   ```
   'has_archive' => 'd',
   'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'd'),
   ```

I can't seem to find any information on keeping the regularly set permalink structure (`/%postname%/%post_id%/`), but with a static prefix (`/d/`) that also accesses `archive.php`.

I would prefer to do this within `register_post_type()`, but if that's not possible, I'm looking for the simplest solution that taxes performance the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/369350) to a similar question, so be sure to check it out because you can just use the same code, except you'd use the post type `dvposts` and not `ex_article`, and use the structure `d/%dvposts%/%post_id%`.

But the trick there is quite simple: When you call [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) with rewriting enabled, WordPress always appends the post slug placeholder (e.g. `%dvposts%` in your case) to the post type's rewrite *slug* (see example below) and stores the permalink structure for that post type in the `$extra_permastructs` property of the [`WP_Rewrite` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/), so we can use that property to make the permalink structure ends with something else, e.g. the post ID in your case:

```php
// AFTER you registered the post type:
register_post_type( 'dvposts', [ 'rewrite' => [ 'slug' => 'd' ], ... ] );
// I.e. register_post_type( '<post type slug>', [ your CPT args here ] );
// And the above would give us this permalink structure: d/%dvposts%, i.e. d/<post slug>

// .. override the permalink structure:
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['dvposts']['struct'] = 'd/%dvposts%/%post_id%';
// I.e. $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['<post type slug>']['struct'] = '<your structure>';
// And now we'd have this permalink structure instead: d/%dvposts%/%post_id%, i.e. d/<post slug>/<post ID>
```

So as you can see, we can completely override the whole permalink structure and not just adding something at the end. And in the future, WordPress might add an API for us so that we don't need to directly access `WP_Rewrite::$extra_permastructs` (to change *just the `struct` value*), but for now, that's the *easy* way to do it. :)

Additionally, `%post_id%` is a registered *rewrite tag* (or placeholder) in WordPress core, so there's no need to call [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_tag/).

### Update

Despite `%post_id%` is a built-in rewrite tag in WordPress core, you actually still need to manually replace it for custom post types, because otherwise, the tag will remain as-is in the permalink URL (e.g. `example.com/d/post-slug/%post_id%`).

And you can use the [`post_type_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) to replace that tag with the correct post ID:

```php
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function ( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( $post && 'dvposts' === $post->post_type ) {
        return str_replace( '%post_id%', $post->ID, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

And as I said in the linked answer, *don't forget to **flush/regenerate** the rewrite rules*! Just visit the permalink settings page without having to click on the "save" button. :)

Comment: Yes, worked very well. Thank you. I added the filter part that makes the answer complete. Without it, the permalink structure makes `%post_id%` a literal string, so every post was appended literally "%post_id%". Apparently the filter just searches for that string then replaces with the actual post id, right?

Comment: BTW, I updated the question as well to show the other option for the `$args`, which is listed as item 4. That is what I'm currently using, don't know if that matters with this solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what the filter callback does - it replaces the `%post_id%` with the actual post ID. And about that item 4, you are doing it correctly - just make sure rewriting is enabled for the post type, i.e. use at least `'rewrite' => true` - but that's actually the default, so the `rewrite` arg can be omitted to simply enable rewriting for the post type.